# Is it different to store account in dotenv and other source code files?

Tags: dotenv

Most of them keep tokens or accounts separately in the dotenv file.
is it different from just saving it as a variable in another source code file and import it for use?

I've been studying API these days, and I've been wondering how to store sensitive content.

Comment: The .env file is normally not checked in.

Comment: @luk2302 What does check in mean?

Comment: Other phrase for not committed. I am hoping your are using some Version control...